# Rendering a pdf/ppt document in a jquery mobile web page

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, jquery-mobile

I am developing a jquery-mobile learning portal. And i would like to render pdf and ppt documents like slideshare does or google books. i have tried lloking around but i can't seem to get any API that can enable me do that. I saw PDF.js but it seems too heavy for mobile and besides it requires a lot of work styling it.
Any assistance ... will be appreciated

Comment: Presumably it would be better to convert your document on the server, where you don't need to worry about your (mobile) environment at all. PDFs will convert nicely to PNG images via ImageMagick. Not sure about PPTs as they're a proprietary format, but a renderer might exist; do a web search for 'ppt bitmap convert php' or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out [Scribd's API](http://www.scribd.com/developers)?

Comment: I have looked at the Scribd API but it seems i have to pay for the enterprise edition if i am to host the documents locally. I wished to have the documents locally.